# summary Tree problems SQL

Tags: sql-server, tree, treeview, hierarchy

> This is my result from my code but i will summary for exampel nodid 1.1 and 1.2 
>   Report: Invoice Appendix

1. > InvoiceNo  8027944
   >   ExtRef:    1600056051
   >   Ordered amount 3 395 300,00 kr
   >   Ordername  Registrering i Fenix E
   >   Rest:  3 395 300,00 kr
   >   Invoice Date   2012-11-06
2. This is my output but this not right

   > ```
   >  Our reference   Nod_id     In nodid   amount
   > 1960110000       1.1        1              0,00    
   > 1960110001       1.1.1      1.1        29000,00       
   > 1960120000       1.1.2      1.1         5000,00
   > 1960130000       1.2        1              0,00
   > 1960130001       1.2.1      1.2         1920,00
   > ```

> 

1. I have this output

> ```
>  Our reference   Nod_id     In nodid   amount
> 1960110000       1.1        1          34000,00<br>
> 1960130000       1.2        1           1920,00</li>
> ```
>
> My problem is I will Summury for exampel Row whit Nod_id 1.1 and 1.2 but i will have our reference 1960110000 and Description Pos 1 ......
>   my code

```
sql, 1 DBSELECT 
t.project,
t.work_order as projakt,
t1.orderram,
t2.flag ,
t2.ext_inv_ref,
t2.work_order,
t2.used_hrs,
t2.cur_amount as belopp,
t4.description, 
t5.nod_id_2 as ing_nodid,
t5.nod_id_1 as nodid,
t5.ingar_pakt as namn,
t2.work_order,
SUM(t2.used_hrs) as used_hrs,
SUM(t2.cur_amount) as belopp
from  atsworkorder t
left join  afx01projact4  t5 on t.client =t5.client and t.work_order = t5.dim_value and t5.attribute_id = 'BF' 
left join afx01projact2  t1 on t.client=t1.client and t.work_order = t1.dim_value
left join atsinvhistr t2 on t.client=t2.client and t.work_order  = t2.work_order and '<datum>' >= t2.voucher_date
left join agldescription t4 on t.client =t4.client and t4.dim_value = t.work_order
where  t.project ='<proj>'  and t.client = '<client>'  
group by
t.project,
t.work_order,
t2.work_order,
t5.nod_id_1,
t5.dim_value,
t5.nod_id_2 ,
t5.ingar_pakt ,
t1.orderram,
t2.flag,
t2.ext_inv_ref,
t2.used_hrs,
t2.cur_amount,
t4.description
order by nodid
```

Comment: It seems like you want to group by or join on the first 3 characters of nod_id (using `SUBSTRING(nod_id, 1, 3)`), if not, can you clarify what exactly you want?

Comment: Seems a lot like you just re-asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218796/tree-problems-sql)

Comment: In this example yes I can using but if I move a node for exampel 1960130001 1.2.1 1.2 1920,00 to node 1960130001 1.2.1 1.1 1920,00 if I using a substring so be this wrong because the child have move to a another parent node 1.1

Comment: Do you just want children of `1` in the output? And I presume you want these recursively added up (so add children, children of children, children of children of children, etc.).

Comment: Yes and I will choose level to